# Error on retrieving data from sqlite database in .net maui

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

Hello I'm trying to build a quiz app to build a quiz app where questions will be retrieved from an sqlite database called cbt.db in a Data folder in my project. However, whenever I run the app it returns this error: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'" in the line the has `currentQuestion = Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];` in the QuizViewModel. I have tried setting the _currentQuestionIndex to 1, but it still doesn't work. I just want to populate a label with the first question before I work on the quiz logic.

The structure of the database is as follows:

There is a Question table which has a question_id that starts from 1, and question_text field. There is also an Answer table which also has a question_id, answer_id, answer_text and is_correct fields. the answer_id is for each individual answer where the question_id maps to that of the Question table.

Here is my Model class: Question.cs

```
using ColumnAttribute = SQLite.ColumnAttribute;

namespace CBT.Models;


public class Question
{
    [Column("question_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("question_text")]
    public string? QuestionText { get; set; }

    [Column("category_id")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public List<Answer>? Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    [Column("question_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("answer_id")]
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }

    [Column("answer_text")]
    public string? AnswerText { get; set; }

    [Column("is_correct")]
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the DBService Interface: IDBService.cs

```
namespace CBT.Services;

public interface IDBService
{
    Task<List<Question>> GetQuestionsAsync();
    Task<Question> GetQuestionAsync(int id);
    Task<int> SaveQuestionAsync(Question question);
    Task<int> DeleteQuestionAsync(int id);

    Task<List<Answer>> GetAnswersAsync();
    Task<Answer> GetAnswerAsync(int id);
}
```

Here is the DBService.cs

```
using CBT.Models;

namespace CBT.Services;

class DBService : IDBService
{
    // The database connection object
    public static SQLiteAsyncConnection? database;

    // Get the database path from the app data directory
    public static string DBPath { get; } = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CBT_App.Data.cbt.db");

    // The constructor initializes the database connection and creates the table if not exists
    public DBService()
    {
        // Create the table for the question model class if not exists
        database.CreateTableAsync<Question>();

        // Create the table for the answer model class if not exists
        database.CreateTableAsync<Answer>();
    }

    // This method returns a list of all items in the database
    public async Task<List<Question>> GetQuestionsAsync()
    {
        return await database.Table<Question>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<Answer>> GetAnswersAsync()
    {
        return await database.Table<Answer>().ToListAsync();
    }

    // This method returns a specific item by its id
    public async Task<Question> GetQuestionAsync(int id)
    {
        return await database.Table<Question>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
    public async Task<Answer> GetAnswerAsync(int id)
    {
        return await database.Table<Answer>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    // This method inserts a new item or updates an existing one
    public async Task<int> SaveQuestionAsync(Question question)
    {
        if (question.Id != 0)
        {
            // Update an existing item
            return await database.UpdateAsync(question);
        }
        else
        {
            // Insert a new item
            return await database.InsertAsync(question);
        }
    }

    // This method deletes an item by its id
    public async Task<int> DeleteQuestionAsync(int id)
    {
        return await database.DeleteAsync<Question>(id);
    }

}
```

Here is the App.xaml.cs

```
namespace CBT;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        if(!File.Exists(DBService.DBPath))
        {
            var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(App)).Assembly;
            using Stream? stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("CBT.Data.cbt.db");
            using MemoryStream? memoryStream = new();
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            File.WriteAllBytes(DBService.DBPath, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        DBService.database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DBService.DBPath, Constants.Flags);

        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Here is the QuizViewModel.cs

```
namespace CBT.ViewModels;

public partial class QuizViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    readonly IDBService dbService;
    private int _currentQuestionIndex;
    private int _currentAnswerIndex;
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; } = [];
    //public Question? currentQuestion => Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
    public ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; } = [];
    //public Answer currentAnswer => Answers[_currentAnswerIndex];

    [ObservableProperty]
    public Question currentQuestion;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public Answer currentAnswer;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string? currentAnswerText;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool currentAnswerIsCorrect;
  
    public QuizViewModel(IDBService dBService)
    {
        this.dbService = dBService;
        Task getQuestionsAsync = GetQuestionsAsync();
        Task getAnswersAsync = GetAnswersAsync();

        currentQuestion = Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
        currentAnswer = Answers[_currentAnswerIndex];

        currentAnswerText = CurrentQuestion.Answers[_currentAnswerIndex].AnswerText;
        currentAnswerIsCorrect = CurrentQuestion.Answers[_currentAnswerIndex].IsCorrect;

        NextQuestion();
        NextAnswers();

    }

    

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetQuestionsAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var questions = await dbService.GetQuestionsAsync();
            if(questions.Count != 0)
            {
                Questions.Clear();
            }
            foreach(var question in questions)
            {
                Questions.Add(question);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print($"Unable to get questions: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetAnswersAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var answers = await dbService.GetAnswersAsync();
            if (answers.Count != 0)
            {
                Answers.Clear();
            }
            foreach (var answer in answers)
            {
                Answers.Add(answer);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print($"Unable to get answers: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void NextQuestion()
    {
        if (_currentQuestionIndex < Questions.Count - 1)
        {
            _currentQuestionIndex++;
            _currentAnswerIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void NextAnswers()
    {
        if (_currentAnswerIndex < CurrentQuestion.Answers.Count - 1)
        {
            _currentAnswerIndex ++;
        }
    }

    
}
```

QuizPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CBT.Views.QuizPage"
             Title="QuizPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CBT.ViewModels"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:CBT.Models"
             x:DataType="vm:QuizViewModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="questionLabel"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="answer1Label"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="answer2Label"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="answer3Label"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="answer4Label"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

QuizPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace CBT.Views;

public partial class QuizPage : ContentPage
{
    public QuizPage(QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Populate(quizViewModel);
    }

    public void Populate(QuizViewModel quizViewModel)
    {
        questionLabel.Text = quizViewModel.CurrentQuestion.QuestionText;
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="CBT.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:CBT.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CBT">

    <ShellContent
        Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
        Title="Main"
        Icon="iconblank.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:QuizPage}"
        Route="QuizPage" />
</Shell>
```

Constants.cs

```
namespace CBT
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            // open the database in read/write mode
            SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite |
            // create the database if it doesn't exist
            SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
            // enable multi-threaded database access
            SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
namespace CBT;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkitCore();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDBService, DBService>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();

        builder.Services.AddTransient<QuizViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<QuizPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

GlobalUsings.cs

```
global using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
global using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
global using CBT.ViewModels;
global using CBT.Views;
global using CBT.Models;
global using CBT.Services;
global using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
global using System.ComponentModel;
global using System.Diagnostics;
global using System.Globalization;
global using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
global using System.Text.Json;
global using System.Threading.Tasks;
global using System;
global using System.Reflection;
global using System.Collections.Generic;
global using System.Linq;
global using System.Text;
global using SQLite;
global using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
global using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;
```

Comment: Problem is your `QuizViewModel` ctor. The `Questions` aren't filled, yet when you try to access this. Mind that Constructors _cannot be async_.

Comment: please post the relevant code, not every single line of code in your app.  This is a pretty basic error - you're trying to retrieve an element of an array that does not exist.  In this case `Questions` is empty because you have not added any data to it.  This line `Task getQuestionsAsync = GetQuestionsAsync();` creates a `Task` but does not actually execute it

Comment: You should separate creating the ViewModel object (ctor) and its initialization with data. Of course, your UI will have to support that initial state of that ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
> non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter
> 'index')'" in the line the has currentQuestion =
> Questions[_currentQuestionIndex]; in the QuizViewModel

The reason for the error is that there is no item in the list at the value of index(`_currentQuestionIndex`).

And from the code you shared, we could find you want to access the element in `Questions` with code `currentQuestion = Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];`, but the `Questions` doesn't has not the element after code  `Task getQuestionsAsync = GetQuestionsAsync();` at this time. This line of code  `currentAnswer = Answers[_currentAnswerIndex];` is also very likely to have this problem.

```
public QuizViewModel(IDBService dBService)
{
    this.dbService = dBService;
    Task getQuestionsAsync = GetQuestionsAsync();
    Task getAnswersAsync = GetAnswersAsync();

    currentQuestion = Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
    currentAnswer = Answers[_currentAnswerIndex];

    currentAnswerText = CurrentQuestion.Answers[_currentAnswerIndex].AnswerText;
    currentAnswerIsCorrect = CurrentQuestion.Answers[_currentAnswerIndex].IsCorrect;
}
```

But you can add a judgment statement before accessing it, for example:

```
   if (Questions != null )
        {
            if (Questions.Count > 0 && _currentQuestionIndex >= 0 && _currentQuestionIndex < Questions.Count)
            {
                currentQuestion = Questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("can not get the element");
            }
        }
```